# Android Button Text offset in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm creating a calculator to learn the basics of programming using Android Studio. In my creation of a very basic RelativeLayout for the standard calculator screen the first button on the screen has text out of alignment from all the other buttons. (It is even on other screens such as the scientific and programming activities) Why would one single button just display the text out of alignment? Note its the same on the physical phone as it is in the simulator phone screen so its not some type of simulator / actual hardware difference. I drew a line on the image to better show the alignment difference example. Also tried Gravity="Center" and it does not change the text alignment.

```
Button
    android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mytextView"
    android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="MC" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_mr"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stnd_btn_sqrt"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
    android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
    android:text="MR" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_mplus"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stnd_btn_exp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_mr"
    android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
    android:text="M+" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_Memoryminus"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stnd_btn_overx"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_mplus"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_mplus"
    android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
    android:text="M-" />
```

[Calculator Simulator Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naUxw.jpg)

This is the XML to the whole page as requested. Thank you.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_standard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.robertgenthner.standardactivity.StandardActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_standard">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="0.00"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <!--FIRST ROW OF BUTTONS START-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mytextView"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:text="MC" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_mr"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stnd_btn_sqrt"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
        android:text="MR" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_mplus"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stnd_btn_exp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_mr"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
        android:text="M+" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_Memoryminus"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stnd_btn_overx"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_mplus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_mplus"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
        android:text="M-" />
    <!--FIRST ROW OF BUTTONS END-->
    <!--SECOND ROW OF BUTTONS START-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_percent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stnd_btn_mr"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:text="%" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_sqrt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stnd_btn_percent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_percent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_percent"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="√" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_exp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_sqrt"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_sqrt"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_sqrt"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="X^2" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_overx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stnd_btn_exp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_exp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_exp"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="1/X" />
    <!--SECOND ROW OF BUTTONS END-->
    <!--THIRD ROW OF BUTTONS START-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_ce"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stnd_btn_percent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:text="CE" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_c"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/stnd_btn_ce"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_ce"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_ce"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_ce"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="C" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_bksp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_c"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_c"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_c"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="bksp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_divide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stnd_btn_bksp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_bksp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_bksp"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="÷" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stnd_btn_bksp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_numbers"
        android:text="7" />
    <!--THIRD ROW OF BUTTONS END-->
    <!--FORTH ROW OF BUTTONS START-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stnd_btn_7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_7"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_numbers"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="8" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_8"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_numbers"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="9" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_multiply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stnd_btn_9"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_9"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="X" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stnd_btn_7"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_numbers"
        android:text="4" />
    <!--FORTH ROW OF BUTTONS END-->
    <!--FIFTH ROW OF BUTTONS START-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stnd_btn_4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_4"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_numbers"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="5" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_5"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_numbers"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="6" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_minus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stnd_btn_6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_6"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="-" />
    <!--FIFTH ROW OF BUTTONS END-->
    <!--SIXTH ROW OF BUTTONS START-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stnd_btn_4"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_numbers"
        android:text="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stnd_btn_1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_1"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_numbers"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="2" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_2"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_numbers"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="3" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stnd_btn_3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_3"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="+" />
    <!--SIXTH ROW OF BUTTONS END-->
    <!--SEVENTH ROW OF BUTTONS START-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_posneg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stnd_btn_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:text="±" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stnd_btn_posneg"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_posneg"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_posneg"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_numbers"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_period"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stnd_btn_0"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_0"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="." />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_equal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/stnd_btn_period"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stnd_btn_period"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stnd_btn_period"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_functions"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="=" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the paddingTop from the first button the text should line up

Edit:

To tidy up the code you could also try to use a Grid layout (Saves having to align everything manually)

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_column="4">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
        android:text="MC" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_mr"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
        android:text="MR" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_mplus"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
        android:text="M+" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_Memoryminus"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
        android:text="M-" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Altered the Code to

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/stnd_btn_mc"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mytextView"
        android:onClick="stnd_btn_memory"
        android:gravity="center"
        
        android:text="MC" />

It is still offset on the single button first in the first row.

Comment: Can you add the full file?

Comment: I updated the post with the full XML file. Thank you.

Comment: Isaac I had to clean it up to work with the other buttons such as the row count but that did clean up a lot of alignment code and it did fix the text alignment issues I wanted to note about the changes I made to help others reading this post later
<GridLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="7"
    android:layout_gravity="center">